# How to make text centered in the middle of a circle with react native svg?

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

This one is simple, but I'm kind of lost.

How can I make the Text in the middle (vertical and horizontal) of the circle? Or everything in the middle of the `Svg` (and then the text will be in the middle of the circle)

```
const size = width < height ? width - 32 : height - 16
const strokeWidth = 25
const radius = (size - strokeWidth) / 2
const circunference = radius * 2 * Math.PI

return (
    <Svg width={width} height={size}>
        <Text>
            Hey
        </Text>
        <Circle
            stroke="#2162cc"
            fill="none"
            cx={size / 2}
            cy={size / 2}
            r={radius}
            strokeDasharray={`${circunference} ${circunference}`}
            {...{ strokeWidth, strokeDashoffset }}
        />
    </Svg>
)
```

Comment: If you want the `Hey` text to be inside `Circle` component then you will have to put this as child in `Circle` and then to keep it in center you can use css `alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'`...... OR else you will have to make the text component `position: absolute` (Not Recommended)

Comment: @MilindAgrawal Could you please provide a full example? Not sure what you mean on your comment

Comment: If you can create a demo link then maybe I can make the changes and share with you.

Comment: @MilindAgrawal everything you need is in the question, and it's very simple, everything is from `react-native-svg`

Answer (score 7):

You will have to use `Text` component from `react-native-svg` as shown below. Hope this helps

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Svg, { Circle, Text } from "react-native-svg";

class Demo extends Component {
  render() {
    const width = 100;
    const height = 100;
    const size = width < height ? width - 32 : height - 16;
    const strokeWidth = 25;
    const radius = (size - strokeWidth) / 2;
    const circunference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;

    return (
      <Svg width={width} height={size}>
        <Text
          stroke="purple"
          fontSize="15"
          x={size / 2}
          y={size / 2}
          textAnchor="middle"
        >
          Hey
        </Text>
        <Circle
          stroke="#2162cc"
          fill="none"
          cx={size / 2}
          cy={size / 2}
          r={radius}
          strokeDasharray={`${circunference} ${circunference}`}
        />
      </Svg>
    );
  }
}

export default Demo;
```

Comment: Using TS gives error the Svg Text has no `children` property.... I wonder why

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the top SVG element in a View element, then, use position absolute to position the circle to act as a background (add 'padding' using `top: 3, left: 3`, if you need some padding for the circle not to be cut out).

Set `alignItems:'center', justifyContent: 'center'` on the most outer View element, to align the text to the center of the view.

### Example

```
<View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{position: 'absolute'}}>
      <Svg width={width} height={size} >
          <Circle
              stroke="#2162cc"
              fill="none"
              cx={size / 2}
              cy={size / 2}
              r={radius}
              strokeDasharray={`${circunference} ${circunference}`}
              {...{ strokeWidth, strokeDashoffset }}
          />
      </Svg>
      <Text>
         Hey
      </Text>
   </View>
</View>
```

### Note

This solution will work for any type of element you want to center, no matter how complex, not just for simple text.

Comment: Note that the code will only work if you move the second line of `View` to above the `Text`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to Daniel's one but focuses on `<Text />`.

Wrap all in a `<View />` with `style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}` to keep all centered. Then add to your text `style={{ position: 'absolute' }}`.

```
return (
   <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
     <Svg width={width} height={size}>
        <Text style={{ position: 'absolute' }}>
            Hey
        </Text>
        <Circle
            stroke="#2162cc"
            fill="none"
            cx={size / 2}
            cy={size / 2}
            r={radius}
            strokeDasharray={`${circunference} ${circunference}`}
            {...{ strokeWidth, strokeDashoffset }}
        />
     </Svg>
   </View>
)
```